# distrotest.net does not have enough space to install Manjaro

Tags: manjaro

As you probably know, there's this website called `distrotest.net` which lest's you try Linux distros on your web browser. I am trying to test Manjaro OS (kde version)using this website. but when the VM starts and takes me to Manjaro's installation page. It says that I can't continue the installation because there isn't enough space on my hard drive! It says that the system must have at least 7.9 GB. Also the system is not connected to the Internet. How do I fix this?

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with the administrators of the web site and its virtualization environment than something U&L can help with

Comment: I guessed that too. Just wanted to make sure. Thank's for the response!

Comment: I'm pretty sure all the distros (or at least the ones I've personally tried) are like that on distrotest. You're not meant to install it there. You're meant to use either their pre-installed image or the live environment provided by the distro. Your best choice is to try it in your own virtual machine, using either VirtualBox of VMware. When you do it that way (it's easier than you might think) you get full control over what happens and you can assign all the resources that you have/want to it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's regarding another web site's hosting capabilities rather than a specific question within the U&L demesne.